# Баг на jquery.min.js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

у меня есть сайт (htttps://armquiz.ml), это так сайт викторина с Facebook, пользователь должен авторизация через Facebook потом сайт по случайным образом должен видать результат например на какой актёре этот пользователь похож, но когда пользователь дает разрешения через Facebook сайт делает вечерний Ajax загрузку, смотрел через inspect element там ошибка 500 на файле jquery.min.js ( вот ссылка на файлу https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js ) не как не могу понять как исправить проблему пожалуйста помогите

---

Вот скрин, На сайте все написено на армянском

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: РКН vs GOOLE!!! "Пора валить со страны..."

Comment: @RifmaMan сомнительно. чтобы при блокировке вернулся код 500.

Comment: А можно скрин с ошибкой и как вы подключаете библиотеку?

Comment: более того, я что-то не уверен. что автор вообще в РФ находится (:

Comment: @teran видимо "уже свалил со страны" =))

Comment: 500 - это внутренняя ошибка сервера, скорее всего какой-то параметр не отправляется на сервер (или что-то в этом роде), и из-за этого на сервере возникает исключение.